# You use me as a weapon

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> You use me as a weapon,
>   Though I'm more lethal with my friend.
>   Another friend is fatter,
>   Beware what's at my end.
>   I hold your victims down,
>   Or bring them up to you.
>   You reward me with a clean,
>   And when your work is done,
>   you lie me down and my friends too.
>   Then when you no longer need me,
>   You shower or bathe me before,
>   You lock me and my friends up,
>   And I sleep till I'm needed once more.

**What am I?**
**Who are my friends?**

Comment: "Or bring them [to] up to you"  extra word intended?

Comment: mhh OP, why the correct answer is Rubio's one?

Comment: The accepted answer shoud be @lois6b due to the time answered

Comment: @lois6b I do apologise

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil do not apologize. Is your decision. I just was asking what made you select that.

Comment: My initial thought was my finger!. The eye-poking one. :¬c

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are a

> Fork

your friends are:

> Cookware, as knife, spoon..

Because

You use me as a weapon

> A fork is used to pierce

Though I'm more lethal with my friend

> Knife and fork

Another friend is fatter

> Spoon

Beware what's at my end

> Fork tines

I hold your victims down

> Forks hold down food, aka “victims”

Or bring them up to you

> Raise the fork to your mouth

You reward me with a clean

> You eat the food off the fork

And when your work is done

> You have finished eating

you lie me down and my friends too

> Place the fork down, aside the knife and spoon

Then when you no longer need me

> After a meal

You shower or bathe me before

> Wash them

You lock me and my friends up

> In the drawer

And I sleep till I'm needed once more

> Stay there until next meal

Comment: Think you have it! Its a fork and the friend is a knife.

Comment: thanks, @karm,  i couldnt decide if it was the knife or the fork the "who" in this question. the fat friend obvious xD

Comment: @Iois6b, I've updated a few of the missing lines in the riddle. Hope you dont mind.

Comment: sure, thanks! also a lot of UpperCase letters that always forget hahaha

Comment: A verse is missing here

Answer (score 6):

I think you are

> a fork

You use me as a weapon
Though I'm more lethal with my friend
Another friend is fatter
Beware what's at my end

> You stab food with a fork. Though more lethal when accompanied by a knife.
>  Your other friend is a spoon (fatter).
>  We should beware your tines.

I hold your victims down
Or bring them up to you

> holding food down to cut, or lifting bites to your mouth.

You reward me with a clean

> cleaning the food off by eating it

And when your work is done
you lie me down and my friends too

> you set down your silverware when done eating.

Then when you no longer need me
You shower or bathe me before

> Washing dishes, either in a sink (bathing) or dishwasher (showering)

You lock me and my friends up
And I sleep till I'm needed once more

> put them away in the silverware drawer.

What am I?

> A fork

Who are my friends?

> Knife and spoon

Comment: I'm afraid lois6b was quicker

Comment: I took too long to edit my answer, I guess. :)